# Which gadget is suitable for just taking a photo of answers of exam with pc?(The laptop-embedded camera is bad for it)

Tags: camera

My univ require me to take photos of papers of answers of exam and send it via internet and mail papers via post office to the univ to be cheched whether any correction wasn't done or not.

I need the camera which can take a moderate resolution(no blur) photos of answers of exam.

I don't intend to use it to take a scenery.

I just want a cheap camera(I guess it is able to be connected with usb) which can take a photo with no blur of written texts.

Can you tell me your recommendations?

Comment: How old are you?  Are you wanting to cheat on an exam?

Comment: No no. My university is technologically-behind so the system requires me to write the answers on the papers, and takes a photos of answers and mail the paper to the university . To check whether the correction is done or not after the exam.

Comment: How funny my univ which i belong.

Comment: BTW my smartphone has been broken.

Comment: Ah got it.  The way it was worded sounded suspicious ;). For some reason it won't let me upvote the question unless you edit it.  Not sure why...

Comment: In what way is your smartphone broken?  Maybe I could help to fix it :)

Comment: I bought the used smartphone and as I view the large size pdf file on the browser, the smartphone has started been freezed and I pressed the power button to shutdown, then the display showed the dialog which operations(reboot or shutdown) you want to do and as I pressed the "shutdown", the process seemingly started and the display has became dark black till now(over 24_h).

Comment: I'm currently waiting for battery die.

Comment: Oh I missed your sentence, I will edit the question statements later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many inexpensive "webcams", such as [this for ~US$20](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07ZKBQN97). Perhaps your university can provide one from stock. Set it up so that it photographs the size of the paper laid out on the desk, and outline, using tape, the area to place a page.

An alternative is to use a scanner, such as those built into many printers.